# Creating a line break to keep visible tabitems from wrapping when other tabitems become visible

Tags: xaml

I have tried a lot of things without luck. What I'm trying to do is create a XAML TabControl that keeps all of the first five visible TabItems on the first row when the last two hidden TabItems become visible. What I want is for the two last TabItems to wrap when they become visible but keep the first five on the first row. I have tried to use a TextBlock with a LineBreak but when the last two TabItems become visible the fifth TabItem wraps with the new visible last two TabItems. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by giving the collapsed tabs a correct width when they are changed to visible the other tabs are pushed back to the first row of tabs.